# Detect if "SVG Document" ActiveX is enabled in IE9

Tags: javascript, svg, adobe, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to check (preferrably using JavaScript), if the "SVG Document" AddOn is enabled in IE9? And maybe even to deactivate it if so?

[SVG Document AddOn http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/7524/svgie9.png](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/7524/svgie9.png)

I need to do this because the AddOn interferes with a JavaScript-Application I wrote using SVGWeb.

Comment: I can't imagine that JS (by default at least) could deactivate a browser plugin - nefarious sites could cause all sorts of hassle with such a feature. But you could probably deactivate it via a script file that the user downloads and runs on their Windows computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I have found that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect browser capability for SVG and render alternate messages.

Comment: While that's a good advice in general, it really doesn't help my problem. I need to deactivate that particular AddOn if it's enabled. The application works just fine in any version of IE - unless IE9/WIN7+Adobe Addon. This isn't really a question of alternative display for IE.